# Flask: Determine which IP address a request was addressed to

Tags: python, flask, wsgi

I have a Flask application that, when it receives a request, needs to make changes to the local network configuration.  To do this, it needs to know which local IP address the request was addressed to.

Is there a way of determining which IP address a request was addressed to?  Or which interface it arrived on?

Comment: Is your Flask app bound to more than one IP at the same time…?

Comment: @deceze Yes.  It's bound to `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: You can use `request.host` to get the IP/URL the request was sent to.